# How to make input field null after button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, input, placeholder

I want the input field to be empty after I press the search button so that I can see the placeholder text. How can I make this happen?

```
        let inp1 = document.querySelector('#inp1');

        let arrai = ["cake", "apple", "banan"];



          function engine(){
            for(let srch of arrai){
              if (inp1.value === srch) {
                window.location.href = inp1.value+".html"
              } else {
                inp1.focus();
                inp1.style.border = "2px solid red";
                inp1.placeholder = "failed";
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: Your code has a bigger issue....

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: If you set inp1.value = '' inside of the else, it will never find a match for apple or banan

Comment: yes, saw it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your issue is you would need to set the value to be empty to see the placeholder. But your code is only going to work for the first value in your array since you assume if the match is not valid it is wrong. That is not the case since you have not checked all the possibilities.

What you would need to do is alter your check. It would be better to use includes instead of a for loop.

```
function engine(){
  var value = inp1.value.toLowerCase()
  var hasMatch = arrai.includes(value)
  if (hasMatch) {
    window.location.href = value + ".html"        
   } else {
     inp1.value = ''; // what you originally asked for
     inp1.focus();
     inp1.style.border = "2px solid red";
     inp1.placeholder = "failed";
   }
 }
```

to do it with a for loop

```
function engine(){
  var hasMatch = false
  for(let srch of arrai){
    if (inp1.value === srch) {
      window.location.href = inp1.value + ".html"
      hasMatch = true
    }
  }
  if (!hasMatch) {
    inp1.value = '';
    inp1.focus();
    inp1.style.border = "2px solid red";
    inp1.placeholder = "failed";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
inp1.value ='';
```

This will set the input to blank and placeholder should display. If that doesn't work try

```
inp1.innerHTML = '';
```

Generally innreHTML only applies to divs,spans, etc. Inputs have a value.

Comment: It would be value, not innerHTML

Comment: This will end up causing a new problem.

Comment: @epascarello what kind of problem?

Comment: ah that. That wasn't in his question so I didn't elaborate. I just game him the correct syntax that's all.